# Applescript, how to move mouse cursor over a button on a website in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript, mouse

Can anybody tell me how to write an Applescript that can move or hover mouse over a Button on Safari? I've successfully made an Applescript that can click to the button but I don't know how to make the mouse just move there, not clicking. Because I need to download some images from a website that only appear when you hover your mouse over that button (that button can't be clicked).

The website I want to get information (HTML Element) when execute the script:
[https://shopee.vn/Bút-line-đi-nét-chuyên-nghiệp-SAKURA-PIGMA-MICRON-12-size-(0.03-Brush)-BÁN-LẺ-i.22061868.886461468](https://shopee.vn/B%C3%BAt-line-%C4%91i-n%C3%A9t-chuy%C3%AAn-nghi%E1%BB%87p-SAKURA-PIGMA-MICRON-12-size-(0.03-Brush)-B%C3%81N-L%E1%BA%BA-i.22061868.886461468)

My sucessfull click-to-the-button Applescript (This click to the second image on the left):

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('_3ZDC1p')[2].click();" in document 1
end tell
```

or:

```
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1  
    end tell
end clickClassName
clickClassName("_3ZDC1p", 2)
```

So can you tell me how to hover mouse over the button (but not clicking) in a similar way of script like these above? Notice the Button "1.0 Graphic" in the website above is faded, that means it can't be clicked but once you hover your mouse to it, the image on the left appear, i want to get that image so bad. I just need to have a script that can do hovering mouse to that button so the image can be seen. Thanks you!

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way using basic vanilla **AppleScript**, by itself, to *move* the mouse cursor; however there are *third-party utilities* that can do it, one being [**cliclick**](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/); however, you also need to be able to tell it where to move it and that has its own issues.

On a different track, looking at the web page of the **URL** in your OP, I see that looking at the **HTML** to the *target element*, e.g. `"document.getElementsByClassName('_3ZDC1p')[2].innerHTML;"` there is a **URL** for the *image*.

Why not get the **HTML**, parse it to get the **URL**, and download it directly to your system?

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does just that:

```
--  # Get the HTML for the target element.

tell application "Safari" to ¬
    tell front document to ¬
        set innerHTML to do JavaScript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('_3ZDC1p')[2].innerHTML;"

--  # Parse 'innerHTML' to get the URL.

set text item delimiters to {"(", ")"}
set theURL to second text item of innerHTML
set text item delimiters to {}

--  # Set the pathfilename for the saved image,
--  # e.g,: /Users/me/Pictures/1591894262.jpeg
--  # Name is based on seconds since Epoch.

set saveToFileName to POSIX path of ¬
    (path to pictures folder) & ¬
    (do shell script "date +%s")

--  # Define the commands necessary to accomplish
--  # the download base on the OP's URL example.

set shellCMD to "curl -ks " & theURL's quoted form & " -o " & saveToFileName's quoted form & ¬
    "; mv -n " & saveToFileName's quoted form & space & saveToFileName's quoted form & ¬
    ".$(file " & saveToFileName's quoted form & " | awk -F ': | ' '{print tolower($2)}')"

--  # Download the file.

do shell script shellCMD
```

- **Note:** This *example* **AppleScript** *code* is based solely on the **HTML** of the *target element* and what's necessary to automate the process once the target web page is available and is the frontmost **Safari** window.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>